# Number of CLOSE_WAIT with lsof

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I

`lsof | grep CLOSE_WAIT | wc -l`

on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I got the PID and TID displayed.  There are say 70 CLOSE_WAITs on a java proc with x number of threads.

However, if I do

`lsof -i | grep CLOSE_WAIT |wc -l`

I got only 1, which is the java process (no TID).

Does it mean that we can't reliably figure out FS leak by doing lsof -i?  We always have to use "lsof"?

As a sidebar, does anyone know why ELB is not closing the connection?

`java      9645 9863     ubuntu  133u     IPv4              19375      0t0    TCP ip-10-20-187-89:51548->ec2-100-200-86-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
java      9645 9864     ubuntu  133u     IPv4              19375      0t0    TCP ip-10-20-187-89:51548->ec2-100-200-86-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
java      9645 9865     ubuntu  133u     IPv4              19375      0t0    TCP ip-10-20-187-89:51548->ec2-100-200-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
java      9645 9902     ubuntu  133u     IPv4              19375      0t0    TCP ip-10-20-187-89:51548->ec2-100-200-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend consulting [a diagram like this one](http://www4.cs.fau.de/Projects/JX/Projects/TCP/tcpstate.html). A TCP connection is not considered closed each side sends a FIN and gets an ACK.

[As stated here](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states). `CLOSE_WAIT` usually indicates the remote end has sent a FIN and been ACK'd by the local end, but the local end has not sent a FIN.

You're likely not seeing the rest of the CLOSE_WAIT entries with `lsof -i` because the remote address is not being shown. It likely shows as empty.

See also:

https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

https://serverfault.com/questions/450055/lot-of-fin-wait2-close-wait-last-ack-and-time-wait-in-haproxy